# Boundary equation of the trajectory of a closed curve

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Are there analytical/closed form equations for the boundaries of the trajectory traced out by a closed curve (tool) in 2D plane?

[Refer to the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2y1Z.jpg) (The tool does not change orientation. It moves along a trajectory)

---

[image]

---

Perhaps one can find a point on g(x,y)=0 farthest along the normal of f(x,y) = 0 for every point on the trajectory of the tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key search term here is *convolution*, as essentially your tool $A$ is convolved
with the shape $B$ whose boundary is the curve.
The first paper below provides more than you need (in that your moving shape
is rigid):

> In this paper we suggest an algebraic algorithm to compute the exact general sweep boundary
>   of a  2D curved object which moves in its own $xy$ plane along a
>   parametric curve trajectory while
>   changing its shape parametrically. 
>   In this case the general sweep boundary is composed of algebraic
>   curve segments.
>
> ---
>
> [image: Convolution]

---

The second paper below is more specific to your question (despite its
non-descriptive title).

---

> Kim, Myung-Soo, Jae-Woo Ahn, and Soon-Bum Lim. "An algebraic algorithm to compute the exact general sweep boundary of a 2D curved object." *Information Processing Letters* 47.5 (1993): 221-229.
>
> Bajaj, Chanderjit, and M-S. Kim. "Generation of configuration space obstacles: The case of a moving sphere." *IEEE Journal on Robotics and Automation* 4.1 (1988): 94-99.